# Split a string vector at whitespace

Tags: r, string, vector, split, whitespace

I have the following vector:

```
tmp3 <- c("1500 2", "1500 1", "1510 2", "1510 1", "1520 2", "1520 1", "1530 2", 
"1530 1", "1540 2", "1540 1")
```

I would like to just retain the second number in each of the atoms of this vector, so it would read:

```
c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
```

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 41):

There's probably a better way, but here are two approaches with `strsplit()`:

```
as.numeric(data.frame(strsplit(tmp3, " "))[2,])
as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(tmp3," "), function(x) x[2]))
```

The as.numeric() may not be necessary if you can use characters...

Comment: This is an elegant solution.  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use your solution but instead, using the column of a data frame and it didn't work straight away. I would add that for those cases you need to turn it into a list. `as.numeric(data.frame(strsplit(as.list(df$columnx), " "))[2,])`

Answer (score 21):

One could use `read.table` on `textConnection`:

```
X <- read.table(textConnection(tmp3))
```

then

```
> str(X)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: int  1500 1500 1510 1510 1520 1520 1530 1530 1540 1540
 $ V2: int  2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

so `X$V2` is what you need.

Answer (score 11):

It depends a little bit on how closely your actual data matches the example data you've given. I you're just trying to get everything after the space, you can use `gsub`:

```
gsub(".+\\s+", "", tmp3)
[1] "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1"
```

If you're trying to implement a rule more complicated than "take everything after the space", you'll need a more complicated regular expresion.

Comment: can you explain this…

Comment: the function `gsub` is for replacing regex matches with something else. In this case, we use the regex `.+\\s+` and replace any matches we find with the empty string `""`. The regex translates to "Match anything in the beginning, but it has to end with a space" (the character space is written as `\\s`)

Answer (score 10):

What I think is the most elegant way to do this

```
>     res <- sapply(strsplit(tmp3, " "), "[[", 2)
```

If you need it to be an integer

```
>     storage.mode(res) <- "integer"
```

Comment: Also, `res <- as.numeric(sapply(...))` works as well; `storage.mode` is a little scary

Answer (score 5):

```
substr(x = tmp3, start = 6, stop = 6)
```

So long as your strings are always the same length, this should do the trick.

(And, of course, you don't have to specify the argument names - `substr(tmp3, 6, 6)` works fine, too)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(strsplit(tmp3, split = " "))[[2]]
```

If you need a numeric vector, use

```
as.numeric(ldply(strsplit(tmp3, split = " "))[[2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `scan()`. To get the second value, we can use a logical subset.

```
scan(text = tmp3)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
#  [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add two more options - using `stringr::str_split()` or `data.table::tstrsplit()`

## 1) using `stringr::str_split()`

```r
# data posted above by the asker
tmp3 <- c("1500 2", "1500 1", "1510 2", "1510 1", "1520 2", "1520 1", "1530 2", 
          "1530 1", "1540 2", "1540 1")

library(stringr)

as.integer(
  str_split(string = tmp3, 
            pattern = "[[:space:]]", 
            simplify = TRUE)[, 2] 
)
#>  [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

`simplify = TRUE` tells `str_split` to return a matrix, then we can index the matrix for the desired column, therefore, the `[, 2]` part

## 2) Using  `data.table::tstrsplit()`

```r
library(data.table)

as.data.table(tmp3)[, tstrsplit(tmp3, split = "[[:space:]]", type.convert = TRUE)][, V2]
#>  [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

`type.convert = TRUE` is responsible for the conversion to integer here, but use this with care for other datasets.
The indexing `[, V2]` part has a similar reason as explained above for `[, 2]`. Here it selects the second column of the returned data table object, which contains the values desired by the asker as integers.

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_4.0.0  magrittr_1.5    tools_4.0.0     htmltools_0.4.0
#>  [5] yaml_2.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    stringi_1.4.6   rmarkdown_2.1  
#>  [9] highr_0.8       knitr_1.28      stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.13      
#> [13] digest_0.6.25   rlang_0.4.6     evaluate_0.14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to split 1 column into 2 columns via data.table

```
require(data.table)  
data_ex = data.table( a = paste( sample(1:3, size=10, replace=TRUE),"-separate", sep="" ))  
data_ex[, number:=  unlist( strsplit(x=a, split="-") )[[1]], by=a]  
data_ex[, word:= unlist( strsplit(x=a, split="-") )[[2]], by=a ]
```