# apply strsplit rowwise

Tags: r, strsplit

Im trying to split a string on "." and create additional columns with the two strings before and after ".".

```
tes<-c("1.abc","2.di","3.lik")
dat<-c(5,3,2)
h<-data.frame(tes,dat)
h$num<-substr(h$tes,1,1)

h$prim<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(h$tes),"\\."))[2]
h$prim<-sapply(h$tes,unlist(strsplit(as.character(h$tes),"\\."))[2])
```

I´d like `h$prim` to contain "abc","di","lik"..However I´m not able to figure it out. I guess `strsplit` is not vectorized, but then I thought the `sapply` version should have worked.  However I assume it should be easy:-)

Regards,
//M

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
R> sapply(strsplit(as.character(h$tes), "\\."), "[[", 2)
[1] "abc" "di"  "lik"
```

Comment: allright.. However not as easy as I thought.. What is this "[[" thing?

Comment: @Misha : the tricky thing about strsplit is that it returns a list. That "[[" thing is the function to extract from that list. 2 is the argument for that function, meaning that it takes the second element of the lists returned by strsplit. See also ?"[[" in R. and thx @rcs, that's clever!

Comment: It's a indexing operator. "[[" can be used to select a single element dropping names, see `?Extract`. You could also use "[".

Comment: @rcs & Joris...Thx for all the help. However still not sure why the h$prim<-sapply(h$tes,unlist(strsplit(as.character(h$tes),"\\."))[2]) doesnt work //Misha

Comment: Because the second argument is not a function, it's just the string "abc"

Comment: @Misha See also my comments to my answer [in very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003527/how-do-i-specify-a-dynamic-position-for-the-start-of-substring/3004225#3004225)

Comment: It could be also call with `fixed` parameter like `strsplit(as.character(h$tes), ".", fixed=TRUE)`. In case of long vectors should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 10):

With the `stringr` package it's even easier:

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(h$tes, fixed("."), 2)[, 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the same as rcs' answer, but may be easier to understand:

```
> sapply(strsplit(as.character(h$tes), "\\."), function(x) x[[2]])
[1] "abc" "di"  "lik"
```

Comment: @all of you... Now I get it. //M

Answer (score 7):

This question appears several time on StackOverflow.

In exact form as yours:

- [Selecting first element of `strsplit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355355/how-to-avoid-a-loop-in-r-selecting-items-from-a-list)
- [Selecting second element separate by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676990/split-a-string-vector-r)
- [Selecting second element separate by dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003527/how-do-i-specify-a-dynamic-position-for-the-start-of-substring) I recommend this question to see in how many ways it could be achieved.

Some similar question in this topic:

- [Split without separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803460/how-to-get-the-second-sub-element-of-every-element-in-a-list-in-r)
- [First part as in your question but was change to more complex case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605527/how-to-pick-up-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-end-of-lines-with-irregular-length-in-r)

And if you care about speed then you should consider [tip from John answer about `fixed` parameter to `strsplit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605527/how-to-pick-up-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-end-of-lines-with-irregular-length-in-r/3606112#3606112).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can save yourself the work of pulling out the 2nd element if you add both columns at the same time:

```
tes <- c("1.abc","2.di","3.lik")
dat <- c(5,3,2)
h <- data.frame(tes, dat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
values <- unlist(strsplit(h$tes, ".", fixed=TRUE))
h <- cbind(h, matrix(values, byrow=TRUE, ncol=2,
                     dimnames=list(NULL, c("num", "prim"))))
```